# Tensorflow object detection model faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid.config is showing following problrm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am using faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oid.config. I shows the following problem. Help me please:

```
  File "train.py", line 167, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\mgp21\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 92, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "C:\Users\mgp21\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\models\research\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 88, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)
  File "C:\Users\mgp21\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 533, in Merge
    descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool)
  File "C:\Users\mgp21\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 587, in MergeLines
    return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
  File "C:\Users\mgp21\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 620, in MergeLines
    self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
  File "C:\Users\mgp21\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 635, in _ParseOrMerge
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
  File "C:\Users\mgp21\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 735, in _MergeField
    merger(tokenizer, message, field)
  File "C:\Users\mgp21\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 823, in _MergeMessageField
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
  File "C:\Users\mgp21\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 703, in _MergeField
    (message_descriptor.full_name, name))
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 160:3 : Message type "object_detection.protos.TrainConfig" has no field named "fine_tune_checkpoint_type".
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of TensorFlow version, you're probably using a newer `.config` with an older TensorFlow, see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4056.